# Video is still downloaded after releasing an AVPlayer instance

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, avplayer

I have problems with my video player that uses the AV Foundation API and plays a clip via HTTP progressive download. Even when the AVPlayer is released, I'm still downloading the video clip (observed via an HTTP Traffic sniffer).

My player is initialized like that:

```
m_player = new AVPlayer();
m_playerLayer = new AVPlayerLayer();
m_playerLayer.Player = m_player;
```

Then, when I have the URL of the video:

```
m_url = new NSUrl (...); 
m_asset = new AVAsset(m_url);
m_asset.AddObserver(this, new NSString ("playable"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, AVPlayerAssetObservationContext);
```

When I'am notified that the asset is playable, I'm creating an AVPlayerItem:

```
m_playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(m_asset);
if (m_player.CurrentItem != m_playerItem)
{
  m_player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem (m_playerItem);    
}
```

My video is playing without any problems. Then, when I press a back button, I have a mechanism that call a Destroy() method. Here I tried a lot of things to be sure that my player is well released:

```
 if(m_player != null)
  {
    m_player.Pause();
    m_player.Dispose();
    m_player = null;
  }

  if(m_playerLayer != null)
  {
    m_playerLayer.Dispose();
    m_playerLayer = null; 
  }


  if(m_playerItem != null)
  {
    m_playerItem.Dispose();
    m_playerItem = null;
  }

  if(m_asset != null)
  {
    m_asset.CancelLoading();
    m_asset.RemoveObserver(this, new NSString("playable"));
    m_asset.Dispose();
    m_asset = null;

  }

  if(m_url != null)
  {
    m_url.Dispose();
    m_url = null;
  }
```

I tested my app with a debugger and for sure, I'am falling into this code. My objects seems to be well released, but for sure the application is still downloading the video url. Am I doing something wrong in the init / release code?

Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: The workaround I found is to add          m_player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(new AVPlayerItem()); The video download is interrupted.

Comment: You should move your comment into an answer and mark this as answered. You should also consider opening a bug report, at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case, because this should (at least) be documented and *maybe* there's something we can do to make it easier (in the API).

Comment: I hope it's enough to put the workaround here :-)

Comment: Does calling [cancelPendingPrerolls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530-CH1-SW48) fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I found is to add this line in the Destroy() code

```
m_player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(new AVPlayerItem());
```

The video download is then interrupted.